# How does one access box plot information? Would like to perform iterative box plot analysis till all outliers are removed?

Tags: r, boxplot

I seem to be facing an issue with the box plot functionality of R. While I have been able to visualize the box plot on RStudio using the boxplot() command, I have not been able to identify the outlier values. How do I do so? I want to be able to remove these values and perform iterative box plot analysis on the data till it is cleansed of all outliers.

To give you a little background, I am trying to remove all the outliers in my dataset in order to find the best possible probability density curve fit as part of my  process simulation project.Currently, for fitting curves to the dataset,I am using the StatFit software module of ProModel.

To sum things up, I would like to remove all the outliers and then print the list of data points within the box.

Thank you,
metalxenophobe93

Comment: See the help file for `boxplot.stats`

Comment: Removing extreme values iteratively is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Very helpful. My sincerest apologies for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> xx = c(1,2,3,4, 12, -20)
> boxplot(xx)
> bb = boxplot(xx)
> bb
$stats
     [,1]
[1,]  1.0
[2,]  1.0
[3,]  2.5
[4,]  4.0
[5,]  4.0

$n
[1] 6

$conf
          [,1]
[1,] 0.5649031
[2,] 4.4350969

$out
[1]  12 -20

$group
[1] 1 1

$names
[1] "1"
```

Outliers:

```
> bb$out
[1]  12 -20
```

To remove all outliers:

```
> xx[!(xx %in% bb$out)]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

To remove all outliers recursively:

```
xx = c(1,2,3,4, 12, -20)
bb = boxplot(xx)
while(length(bb$out <1)){
    xx = xx[!(xx %in% bb$out)]
    bb = boxplot(xx)
}
xx
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Of course every time you remove outliers, if you re-run the boxplot stats, you are likely to find more outliers.

Comment: That is what the OP wants to do: " I want to be able to remove these values and perform iterative box plot analysis on the data till it is cleansed of all outliers". Please see my edit above.

Comment: give a man a fish, you feed him for a day; give him a rope, and he can go hang himself ...